# How to export data from data grid view to pdf in vb

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I had to delete the previous question to re-evaluate my code properly. The last time I tried to print but it got confusing for me, So I did more research on how to export to pdf and wrote the code for it. When I run the program, I was able to save the pdf as it prompted me but after saving the file, the error popped up and read as follows:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get returned Nothing.

This is my code for the export button:

```
 Private Sub btnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    If SaveFileDialog1.FileName = "" Then
        MsgBox("enter filename to create pdf", vbExclamation)
    Else
        ExportDataToPDFTable
        MsgBox("PDF file successfully created!", vbInformation)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub ExportDataToPDFTable()
    Dim paragraph As New Paragraph
    Dim doc As New Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 40, 40, 40, 10)
    Dim wri As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream(SaveFileDialog1.FileName + ".pdf", FileMode.Create))

    Dim font12Bold As New iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8.0F, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)
    Dim font12Normal As New iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8.0F, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)

    doc.Open()

    Dim PdfTable As New PdfPTable(9)
    PdfTable.TotalWidth = 490.0F
    PdfTable.LockedWidth = True

    Dim widths As Single() = New Single() {0.3F, 1.0F, 2.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 0.5F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F}
    PdfTable.SetWidths(widths)
    PdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = 1
    PdfTable.SpacingBefore = 2.0F

    Dim PdfCell As PdfPCell = Nothing

    PdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("id", font12Bold)))
    PdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
    PdfTable.AddCell(PdfCell)

    PdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("date", font12Bold)))
    PdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
    PdfTable.AddCell(PdfCell)

    PdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("brand", font12Bold)))
    PdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left
    PdfTable.AddCell(PdfCell)

    PdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("size", font12Bold)))
    PdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left
    PdfTable.AddCell(PdfCell)

    PdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("selling unit price", font12Bold)))
    PdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left
    PdfTable.AddCell(PdfCell)

    PdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("cost unit price", font12Bold)))
    PdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left
    PdfTable.AddCell(PdfCell)

    PdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("Quantity", font12Bold)))
    PdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left
    PdfTable.AddCell(PdfCell)

    PdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("total selling price", font12Bold)))
    PdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left
    PdfTable.AddCell(PdfCell)

    PdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("total cost price", font12Bold)))
    PdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left
    PdfTable.AddCell(PdfCell)

    PdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("profit", font12Bold)))
    PdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left
    PdfTable.AddCell(PdfCell)


    Dim dt As DataTable = getDataTable()
    If dt IsNot Nothing Then
        For rows As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            For columns As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                PdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(dt.Rows(rows)(columns).ToString, font12Normal))
                If columns = 4 Or columns = 6 Then
                    PdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right
                Else
                    If columns = 0 Or columns = 5 Then
                        PdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
                    Else
                        PdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
        doc.Add(PdfTable)
    End If
    doc.Close()
End Sub
Private Function getDataTable() As DataTable
    Dim DataTable As New DataTable("MyDataTable")
   ' Dim dataColumn1 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
    Dim dataColumn2 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
    Dim dataColumn3 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(3).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
    Dim dataColumn4 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(4).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
    Dim dataColumn5 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(5).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
    Dim dataColumn6 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(6).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
    Dim dataColumn7 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(7).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
    Dim dataColumn8 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(8).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
    Dim dataColumn9 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(9).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
    '  Dim dataColumn10 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(10).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))

    ' DataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn1)
    DataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn2)
    DataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn3)
    DataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn4)
    DataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn5)
    DataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn6)
    DataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn7)
    DataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn8)
    DataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn9)
    '  DataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn10)

    Dim dataRow As DataRow
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        dataRow = DataTable.NewRow
        '  dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString
        dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString
        dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(3).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString
        dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(4).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString
        dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(5).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value.ToString
        dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(6).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value.ToString
        dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(7).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value.ToString
        dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(8).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value.ToString
        dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(9).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value.ToString
        '  dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(10).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value.ToString
    Next

    DataTable.AcceptChanges()
    Return DataTable

End Function
```

With my IMPORTS:

```
 Imports iTextSharp
 Imports iTextSharp.text
 Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
 Imports System.IO
```

The query for retrieving data from the data grid view works fine, but I want the retrieved data from DGV to be exported to pdf once I click the "save as PDF" button. My error is after saving the pdf file, it's where the error has popped up and when opening the pdf file the error says:
screenshot of the error: https://snipboard.io/VF9RKQ.jpg from Adobe PDF
Screenshot of the DGV data after retrieved: https://snipboard.io/r627jz.jpg

I don't know where I went wrong. Why I'm not able to see DGV data on PDF? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, before doing `DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(x).Value.ToString` you must ensure `DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(x).Value` is not empty :

in getDataTable() replace lines

```
dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(x).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(x).Value.ToString
```

by

```
'note : I simplified 'dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(x).HeaderText.ToString)'
dataRow(x) = IIF(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(x).Value is nothing, "", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(x).Value.ToString)
```

IFF statement works like that :
IFF(condition, result if condition is true, result if false) so if cell is empty, datarow will be filled with "".

update : to track errors add try/catch and breakpoint

```
Try
dataRow(2) = IIF(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value is nothing, "", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString)
dataRow(3) = IIF(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value is nothing, "", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString)
dataRow(4) = IIF(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value is nothing, "", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString)
dataRow(5) = IIF(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value is nothing, "", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value.ToString)
dataRow(6) = IIF(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value is nothing, "", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value.ToString)
dataRow(7) = IIF(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value is nothing, "", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value.ToString)
dataRow(8) = IIF(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value is nothing, "", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value.ToString)
dataRow(9) = IIF(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value is nothing, "", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value.ToString)
Catch ex As Exception 'put break point here and look at ex value
End Try
```

Comment: So for the if statement should be as a whole for all or individually? @tuyau2poil

Comment: Its bringing the same error @tuyau2poil

Comment: individually as each cell must be tested :

Comment: I did individually for each cell, but after saving the pdf the problem still persists @tuyau2poil

Comment: Or I'm doing it wrong? is this the way:  @tuyau2poil
dataRow(2) = IIf(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value Is Nothing, "", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString)

Comment: that's correct. you get same error ?

Comment: Yes i still got the same error after saving the PDF

Comment: It says the PDF is either damaged. Screenshot: https://snipboard.io/VF9RKQ.jpg
@tuyau2poil

Comment: put break point in getDataTable() and look at DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(x).Value. you can also put a TRY/CATCH block : I'll update answer.

Comment: I have no knowledge of your pdf creation. answer only ensure dataGridview cells values are correctly reads.